# Reverting to a different file when PHP fails to find a specific file (include function)

Tags: php, warnings, syntax-error

Sorry for you advanced guys, I'm actually teaching myself some PHP so this may seem like a beginner's question.

I'm using a testing server and then uploading to a remote server. The index.php file is located in "C:\XAMPP\htdocs\php_site" on my local pc and in "home/www/myname.atwebpages.com/" on the remote server. Now the code I'm trying to run is just a simple:

```
define ('ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
include ROOT."menu/menu.php";
```

This code works fine for the remote server. However, when attempted on my local machine, it spits out this error:

```
Warning: include(C:/XAMPP/htdocs/menu/menu.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\php_site\index.php on line 21
```

Clearly, it's not looking in the php_site folder. Instead, it's tying to find a menu folder in the htdocs directory, but it's not there. The menu folder is located inside the site folder, php_site. If I chance around the code to work on the local machine, it no longer works on the remote server. I'm a little confused as to how to get around this problem.

Comment: as an aside there seems little point to reallocate the super global to a constant, you could just use the global directly and save some memory

Comment: If I'm following you, you're saying to just point to the root directory directly in the include function rather than defining a "ROOT" variable and then using that. The only reason I defined the root was because I have two definitions of ROOT in the document, one for the local server and one for the remote server. I just comment out the one that is not in use, which is becoming annoying to do every time I'd like to test without uploading to the remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is defined by apache, so you'd need to change the config there. Or, define the ROOT constant relative to where you actually put your files, so if you do something like:

```
define ('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

Put that in a constants file in the same folder as your index.php.

Comment: I did attempt to go into the Apache config files to change that but that would create problems if I were to work on another site (or I'd have to go back in and keep changing the directory in the config files). Either way, it's not a great workaround, I found. Can you detail how to use the dirname()? I mean, which path would I be putting in the "()"?

Comment: Thanks, I got it! For reference, I put your code in my index.php file and simply replaced "__FILE" with "../index.php". Works on both the remote and testing server now.

Comment: mistyped the constant, edited. If you plan on working on multiple sites on ur machine, you can create virtual hosts each with a different dir root.

Answer (score 0):

Your document root on the remote and local machines is different. On your local machine your document root *is* the `htdocs` directory, and the `php_site` folder is merely a sub-folder, and thus the path is wrong.

I suggest either making the `ROOT` directory be a relative directory to the index page, or have a constants file in the root directory of the PHP site that defines the root directory as the directory it is in (which would be in the `php_site` directory on your local machine, the same directory as your index page). `define ('ROOT', dirname(__FILE));` would work in this situation.

Another idea is to use a try-catch to catch the failure of the include statement, and attempt to try another directory, perhaps using `define ('ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` first, and if it fails, attempt to use `define ('ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'php_site/');` instead.